# Flutter linear gradient is not smooth (has strange lines)

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a problem with the LinearGradient in flutter. I am adding gradient to the BoxDecoration but it is not working as expected(both on deploy and on local build). How I've done it:

```
BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
                Colors.red,
                Colors.green,
      ],
    ,)
 ,);
```

And here is the result how it appears: [image]

As you can see there are strange lines, like it is not smooth. I have tried with adding `Paint.enableDithering = true;`, but it is not working for me. Has anyone deal with that problem and what solution you came up with. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you to add some colors in between red and green. Probably this can help you: https://learnui.design/tools/gradient-generator.html

Comment: Maybe its my eyes, but I cannot see non-smoothness in the picture

Comment: There are somethings like lines inside the image, like it is not smooth